# Filter results of a stored query in MS Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

How can I filter a MS Access stored query results stored in a `Recordset` (I can accept another form of a container as well - open to suggestions) with C#.Net?

**What I am trying to do:**

Currently I am getting the results of the stored query in a `Recordset` like so:

```
 using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
 private List<Student> extractValidStudentData(Access.Application iAccess)
    {
        List<Student> extractedStudents = new List<Student>();
        Access.Dao.Database db = iAccess.CurrentDb();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Sec_A_Students"; //Sec_A_Students is the name of the stored query
        Access.Dao.Recordset recordSet = db.OpenRecordset(query,
            Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot);
 ..........................
```

Here I need to filter the `Recordset`/Results of the stored query to find all the duplicates in a certain field (`Mobile_num`), store the first record/row and remove the rest from the `Recordset`, but store them in another container.

I then use the `Recordset` further down below in the function. This part of the code is removed.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya The issue is that I do not know how to query the record set and extract the mentioned information in some sort of a data container.

Comment: you can use ADO.NET to read data from MSAccess.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-microsoft-access-database-in-C-Sharp/ you can read data from database in to Reader and then convert it to `List<Student>` and then use LINQ to get the desired result

Comment: I am aware of the Reader method. It does not provide solution to the question. I do not want to query the List, but the container with the results of the query if of course there is possibility for that to happen.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-filter-property-dao

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/working-with-recordsets

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I guess that can do the job. Can you post an example answer?